# Maven: exclude transitive dependency in some modules

Tags: maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

The project includes 7 modules.
And the task is to exclude transitive dependency for one library in 4 modules.

Seemingly simple way is to write in each of 4 pom files:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
<artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
<version>3.4.1</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

But is there a more optimal way?
Could I, for example, create one separate util pom.xml with dependencyManagment, and "link" this pom with each module, where I want to apply this dependencyManagment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define this in the parent POM and it then be used in all modules.